# Did they really sell toy guns along with newspaper during K. M. Nanavati trial?

Tags: plot-explanation, rustom

In *Rustom*, a paperboy is shown selling **toy guns** along with newspapers.

This movie based on this [case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._M._Nanavati_v._State_of_Maharashtra).

[image]

Actually Gun here symbolizes *Rustom*'s gun which was used to kill Vikram.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes they did.

> Peddlers on the street sold Ahuja Towels and toy Nanavati Revolvers.

**[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K._M._Nanavati_v._State_of_Maharashtra#reference)**